# Oracle apex validation message

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have added two validations in my page for the items 'New Password' and 'Retype Password'. Error message display location is set at inline with field. But when validation executes I get an error message, displaying total errors in the page "2 error have occurred" at the top of the page. How can I hide this error message which is showing at top of the page: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.t-Body-alert{
    visibility: hidden;
     height: 0px;
}
```

add the above code to CSS inline of the page, it will hide the total error displayed at the top of the page. **Please note** that this will hide your 'apex_aplication.g_print_success_message'

Answer (score 0):

You could set the Validation's **Display Location** property to "Inline with Field" rather than "Inline with Field and in Notification".

If you want this behaviour everywhere you can change the application-level **Default Error Display Location** to "Inline with Field" in the **Error Handling** tab of Application Properties.

Comment: current error display location is "inline with field", and the vaidation error shows with field. but the problem is, at the first line of the page it shows total number of errors in validation(see the image, you can see error message- "2 errors have occured" ) . I wanted to hide this and I could solve this by hiding the CSS class of this message. and thank you for the reply tony :)